# Add/calculate lines on multiple criteria with loops based on values in other columns

Tags: excel, vba, loops, for-loop, datatables

I have an excel sheet which looks like the following picture:

[image]

I need to:

1. Add up the Amount and Costs for each Position (all for 1, all for 2, all for 3, ...).
2. Then look for the "X" in Actual and then merge all the Rows where the Position value is equal on this row, so this should be the leading and only remaining row for this position at the end. BUT it should not be in the same sheet, but in a new one. Basically, in this example, there will be a second sheet with three rows (because of 3 Positions in this example)
3. It needs to be dynamic. There can be any amount of positions in here
4. The Description, Date, etc. from the Position with X in Actual should be adopted for each position.
5. There are even more columns and more calculations that need to be done, so it should be easy to add calculation criteria.

I am not an Excel Pro and I think it's not possible to solve this without coding a Makro, so feel free to prove me wrong...

So far I wrote the following VBA code based on some snippets I found online, but unfortunatly got stuck with adding up only specific rows (with the same position number) and output the sum in the position with "x" in Actual:

```
Sub MergeRows()
    Dim r_src As Range, r_dst As Range

    ' Pick 1st row and column of table
    Set r_src = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2")
    Set r_dst = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2")

    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim N_rows As Integer, N_cols As Integer

    'Find the size of the data
    N_rows = CountRows(r_src)
    N_cols = CountColumns(r_src)

    'Resize source range to entire table
    Set r_src = r_src.Resize(N_rows, N_cols)

    Dim src_vals() As Variant, dst_vals() As Variant
    'Get all the values from source
    src_vals = r_src.Value2

    ReDim dst_vals(1 To N_rows, 1 To N_cols)
    Dim k As Integer
    Dim x As Integer
    k = 0
    For i = 1 To N_rows
        For x = 1 To 10
            ' Check first column
            If Val(src_vals(i, 1)) = x Then
                ' Increment count
                k = k + 1
                ' Copy row values

                Dim qty As Integer
                qty = qty + src_vals(i, 27)
                src_vals(i, 27) = qty

                For j = 1 To N_cols
                    If src_vals(i, 2) = "X" Then
                    dst_vals(k, j) = src_vals(i, j)
                    End If
                Next j

            End If
        Next x
        qty = 0
    Next i
    ' Bring rows back into destination range
    If k > 0 Then
        r_dst.Resize(k, N_cols).Value2 = dst_vals
    End If
End Sub
Public Function CountRows(ByRef r As Range) As Integer
    CountRows = r.Worksheet.Range(r, r.End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
End Function
Public Function CountColumns(ByRef r As Range) As Integer
    CountColumns = r.Worksheet.Range("A:DS").Columns.Count
End Function
```

Comment: Can you create the same screenshot how your desired result would look like? That would help to understand what exactly is going to group/sum. • Did you try if PivotTables can be used to produce what you expect?

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, you want to copy each row marked as actual (according that there's only one per position) to an other Worksheet, and sum up all _Costs_ and _Amount_ values of the corresponding position to the one you copied ?

Comment: @Bryan, are you planning to give feedback to answerers?

Comment: @HTH are you in a hurry? He asked only 7 hours ago. Not everyone stays on SO pressing F5 until someone answers. Usually I would write a question and come back in a day or so.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ, I don't stand people who don't care about who helps them. As you could check yourself, he was back lately two hours ago, but not one feedback, not even a "Thanks, I'm gonna see..". And I feel I can ask whatever I want to, sticking to rules

Comment: @HTH still, you don't know, and I think that was a bit harsh. He might have checked on the phone, saw oh there is an answer I will check it later, because I have no time right now. Or his SO tab is still open in the browser, he suspended the notebook, came back to it, website triggers him as seen even if he didn't see it because it was just still open in the background. There might be many reasons. Give him some time.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ It is usually expected of users posting a question to stick around for a while to answer comments. It's in their best interest: That is the time a question is exposed to the most views. "_After you post, leave the question open in your browser for a bit, and see if anyone comments. If you missed an obvious piece of information, be ready to respond by editing your question to include it. If someone posts an answer, be ready to try it out and provide feedback!_" ([How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) under "Post the question and respond to feedback")

Answer (score 3):

Please check this

[image]
*<sup>Image 1: Sorry for the German screenshot.

"Summe von Amount/Costs" means "Sum of Amount/Costs" and "Gesamtergebnis" means "Total result".</sup>*

which can be done with PivotTables (without using VBA) it updates dynamically.
See [Create a PivotTable to analyze worksheet data](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-pivottable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US).

Just add in the PivotTable `Position` to rows, and `Amount` and `Costs` to Values.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need to loop through things, you can do the basic additions with a sumif formulae and then maybe just use a macro to automate applying the formulae on a 2nd sheet and I guess one quick loop to remove empty rows:

You can see the formulae works here:
[image: Correct Totals]

[image: Formulae Shown]

And in the macro you'd just want something like

```
Sub e()
Sheet4.Range("A2:A9").Formula = "=SUM('Sheet_1'!C2:C3)"
Sheet4.Range("B2:B9").Formula = "=IF('Sheet_1'!$B2=""X"",SUMIF('Sheet_1'!$A$2:$E$9,'Sheet_1'!A2,'Sheet_1'!$E$2:$E$9),"""")"
End Sub
```

To apply the formula and then maybe

```
Sheet4.Range("A2:B9").value2 = Sheet4.Range("A2:B9").value2
```

To resolve them to just the numbers.

Then do a quick loop to remove blank values in column B.

---

**NB** You can still make it totally dynamic by subbing my hard-coded ranges for a variable and use your `CountRows` function.